# Can anyone give me a hint of this question?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $u=f(r)$,where $r=\|x\|$ and f is differentiable .

Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Big(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\Big)^2=|f'(r)|^2$ .

Comment: You should also include the "calculus" tag on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a hint: $u(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = f(r) = f(\sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2})$. Now substitute $u$ with the last expression in the sum
$$\sum \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right)^2$$
and compute those partial derivatives as derivatives of a composition.